# How to write SQL inside XML SOAP request - salesforce marketing cloud API

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, soap, xml

I am new to SOAP.

I am trying to get the Send Object information and I am able to pull all the data I need except
`<Properties>SendID</Properties>`

This is the request I make in postman

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <fueloauth>{{sf_ps_access_token}}</fueloauth>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>BCCEmail</Properties>
                <Properties>SendID</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
                <Properties>PartnerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>ModifiedDate</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Email.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>Email.PartnerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>SendDate</Properties>
                <Properties>FromAddress</Properties>
                <Properties>FromName</Properties>
                <Properties>Duplicates</Properties>
                <Properties>InvalidAddresses</Properties>
                <Properties>HardBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>SoftBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>OtherBounces</Properties>
                <Properties>ForwardedEmails</Properties>
                <Properties>UniqueClicks</Properties>
                <Properties>UniqueOpens</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberSent</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberDelivered</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberTargeted</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberErrored</Properties>
                <Properties>NumberExcluded</Properties>
                <Properties>Unsubscribes</Properties>
                <Properties>MissingAddresses</Properties>
                <Properties>Subject</Properties>
                <Properties>PreviewURL</Properties>
                <Properties>SentDate</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailName</Properties>
                <Properties>Status</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailSendDefinition.ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>EmailSendDefinition.CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
                <Properties>Email.PartnerKey</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="ns1:SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                    <Property>CreatedDate</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>between</SimpleOperator>
                    <DateValue>2018-01-01</DateValue>
                    <DateValue>2021-12-09</DateValue>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
<OverallStatus>Error: Column 'dbo.tblJobs.SendID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.</OverallStatus>
```

How do I write SQL inside the xml SOAP request?

Answer (score 1):

So, the reason you are getting this error is because SendID is NOT part of the SOAP **[Send Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/send.html)**. Now, that it is returning a SQL error is very odd (and also very telling that the SOAP object is just a wrapper for a SQL call internally in SFMC to gather this information and pass it back) and likely some sort of 'glitch' on SFMC end of error handling. It usually gives an error more along the lines of 'SendID is not a retrievable property for this object' or something like that.

And finally, the value in `ID` for the send Object is likely what you are looking for to match with JobID.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I`ll try to take a look

Comment: I get the same error when I try to get ListSend Object data and add CreatedDate prop, where as, it is part of the Object....
This is weird

Comment: I am trying to combine data between Send, ListSend, ClickEvent and Subscribers Objects
Subscribers and ClickEvent I use SubscriberKey, 
ClickEvent and ListSend I use SendID
So I am trying to figure out the correct key to combine the data between those and Send

Comment: @EliSigal - this would be another question you would need to create as that is well beyond the original scope of your question. But a word of advice is to use the DESCRIBE SOAP action on those objects to get details on all the properties in the objects as well if they are retrievable.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the describe option. thank you. question posted